# Register endpoints with transactional

Tags: spring, jms, spring-jms

using Spring 5 on Java 1.9

Using a configuration that implements the `JmsListenerConfigurer` to register endpoints:

```
@Configuraiton
public class Endpointer implements JmsListenerConfigurer {

   @Override
    public void configureJmsListeners(JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
      SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();
      ....
   }
}
```

Is there a way when adding the message listener to tell Spring to make it transactional (`@Transactional`)?  Would also love to be able to use message converters.  Rather than pass an onMessage like method to the endpoint's `setMessageListener` I would like lambda that took a string (i.e. a converter is run taking the message to a string) and be able to receive jms headers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not making this a Spring Bean
*SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint endpoint = new SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint();*

make this a spring bean and add @Transactional

Comment: Thought transactional (attribute) was only for methods not beans and what do you mean by making the endpoint a bean? The simple listener only takes a method listener not a bean like MethodJmsLisyenerEmdpoint as is done internally by Spring when resolving JmsListener.

Comment: SimpleJmsListenerEndpoint.onMessage(..) . use @Transational on that.